# Array Search and Checkboxes

Tags: php, html

i cant seem to make the checkbox appear as checked if this statement turns out to be true. the array passed is working fine and everything is in palce but i dont seem to find a way where i can make the checkbox checked if the value of BSS is there

```
      <?php if(isset($_GET['cng']) && array_search("BSS", $scharr))
      {
        echo "checked=''";
      };

      ?>/>
      BSS
      </label>
```

Comment: Maybe you need `in_array`?

Comment: add full code with checkbox input

Comment: the array output looks like this Array ( [0] => BSS [1] => SISA [2] => NGS ) there are atleast 10 more inputs like this in the function                                                                                                          
             <label for="one">
          <input type="checkbox"  name="school[]" value="BSS" 
          
          <?php if(isset($_GET['cng']) && array_search("BSS", $scharr))
          {
           echo "checked=''";
          };

          ?>/>
          BSS
          </label>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:

```
<label for="one"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="school[]" value="BSS" <?php echo isset( $_GET['cng'] ) && in_array("BSS", $scharr) ? 'checked' : ''; }; ?> /> 
BSS </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php if(isset($_GET['cng']) && isset($scharr['BSS'])) echo "checked"?> />
```

Comment: $scharr['BSS'] it check the key (if associative array is there)

Comment: I assume that `$scharr` must be associative, that's becuase `array_search` doesn't work. But you're right, if it would be associative `isset` works

Comment: i attached the remaining of the code but this one didnt work ...... im not sure what am i doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php if(isset($_GET['cng']) && array_search("BSS", $scharr)) { echo "checked";}>
```